# How to create query for embedding object in another embedded object(already embedded object)?

Tags: java, mongodb

I have added an embedded object in one collection. The object appears as below

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("506d3046a4e89e856eace0cc"),
    "name": "new"
    "menuList":[{
        "name":"dssdfDS",
        "des":"dsfsdf",
        "_id" : ObjectId("506d3046a4d89e856eace0cc")
    }]
}
```

I have created BasicDBObject query to push "menuList" to the **"name":"new"**, I have done this successfully, Now i want to append menuList1 to menuList.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("506d3046a4e89e856eace0cc"),
    "name": "new"
    "menuList":[{
        "name":"dssdfDS",
        "des":"dsfsdf",
        "_id" : ObjectId("506d3046a4d89e856eace0cc")
        "menuList1":[{
            "name":"dssdfDS",
            "des":"dsfsdf",
            "_id" : ObjectId("506d3046a4d89e856eace0cc")
        }]
    }]
}
```

How do I make a **BasicDBObject query** to update **menuList** by pushing **menuList1** inside **menuList**?

Answer (score 0):

Following query do the trick

```
  BasicDBObject query= new BasicDBObject("_id", ObjectId("506d3046a4e89e856eace0cc"));
  query.append("menuList._id", ObjectId("506d3046a4d89e856eace0cc"));

  BasicDBObject update = new BasicDBObject();
  update.append("menuList.$.menuList1", menuList1Objects);

  BasicDBObject updateCommand = new BasicDBObject("$push", update);

  db.collection.update(query,updateCommand);
```